# Custom Java annotation processor for AST in incremental compilation

Tags: java, netbeans, javac, abstract-syntax-tree, processor

I have this scenario: two maven modules (jdk6) A and B.

In module A I've defined these classes:

MyBeanAnnotation : an annotation for classes defined like this:

```
package x.y.z;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface MyBeanAnnotation {    
    String name();
}
```

MyAnnProcessor: a class extending AbstractProcessor defined like this:

```
package x.y.z;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("x.y.z.MyBeanAnnotation")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class MyAnnProcessor extends AbstractProcessor{

@Override
public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
    super.init(processingEnv);
}    

@Override
     public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "Hello World!");
}
    return true;
}
}
```

- I've created a text file in META-INF/services named javax.annotation.processing.Processor

  x.y.z.MyAnnProcessor

I can compile it, no problem.

In the module B:

- pom.xml : created a dependency to module A

I've created a class MyAnnotatedBean annotated with MyBeanAnnotation

```
package x.y.z;
import x.y.z.MyBeanAnnotation;

@MyBeanAnnotation(name = "scemochileggee")
public class MyAnnotatedBean {
    private String qweq = "qweq";
}
```

When I compile B from scratch (e.g. mvn clean install), the processor MyAnnProcessror gets correctly called, and I can see the printout in the compiler logs

On the other hand, when I edit it in Netbeans (I've only tried this IDE) and save the MyAnnotatedBean file, nothing happens and the MyAnnProcessor in not invoked.

Do you have any idea if there's a way to make MyProcessor work in incremental compilation as well?

Thanks in advance.